# how to extract API from websites in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am new to the Laravel5 framework , so that I have no idea about this.I want to fetch data from a website and store that in my database.can anyone provide a sample coding that will come under model , view , controller and route, so that I can understand it in better way.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please make sure you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to improve your question. It will make it easier for others to understand it and help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything except something's come under model controller view and routes.

start from the [Tutorials docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) and continue to [The Basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing)

navigate in the left navigation from top to bottom